# $\overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{b}, \overrightarrow{c}$ are on the same plane

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vectors

We want to show that if $\overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{b}, \overrightarrow{c}$ are on the same plane, then there are $A, B, C$ not all $0$ such that $A \vec a+B \vec b+C \vec c=\vec 0$.

$$$$

The solution is the following:

If $\overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{b}, \overrightarrow{c}$ are on the same plane, then

1. all are equal to $\overrightarrow{0}$ and then $1 \cdot \overrightarrow{a} + 1 \cdot \overrightarrow{b}+ 1 \cdot \overrightarrow{c}=\overrightarrow{0}$
2. all are on the same line and one is not the $\overrightarrow{0}$

   for example, $\overrightarrow{a} \neq \overrightarrow{0}$, so $\overrightarrow{b}=m \overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{c}=n\overrightarrow{a}$ and then $-(m+n)\overrightarrow{a}+1\cdot \overrightarrow{b}+1 \overrightarrow{c}=\overrightarrow{0}$
3. two are not the $\overrightarrow{0}$ and don't belong to the same line

   for example, the $\overrightarrow{b}, \overrightarrow{c}$, then $\overrightarrow{a}=x \overrightarrow{b}+y \overrightarrow{c}$ and then $1 \cdot \overrightarrow{a}+(-x) \overrightarrow{b}+(-y) \overrightarrow{c}=\overrightarrow{0}$.

$$$$

Could you explain to me why we take these cases?

Comment: These are all the cases because case 3 basically says "all the other cases". Note that when they say "one/two is not the $\vec0$", they really mean "_at least_ one/two is not the $\vec0$".

Comment: Ok... Thank you!! :-) @Arthur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all zero, or they aren't. If they are, done (case 1).

So, assume they aren't all zero. They are either all on the same line, or they aren't.

- If they are on the same line, and two, one or none of them are zero, you have something to prove (case 2).
- If they are not on the same line, and two of them are zero, then they *are* actually on the same line, and so we don't have to consider this case.
- Finally, if they are not on the same line, and one or none of them are zero, you have 
  something to prove (case 3).

EDIT (in response to your comment below): The way you will construct your argument depends on which case you are considering.

In the first case, we assume they are on the same line, and at least one is non-zero.

Suppose $a$ is non-zero (since the argument is identical if we start by assuming $b$ or $c$ is the non-zero vector). If, additionally, $b$ equals zero, then $0a + 1b + 0c  =0$ and you're done (likewise if $c = 0$, then $0a + 0b + 1c = 0$).

Otherwise, if $b$ is not zero, then, because they are on the same line, there is $\alpha$ so that $a = \alpha b$ so $1 a - \alpha b = 0$.

Comment: Could you explain to me further why we have to take cases whether the vectors are zero or not and whether they are on the same line?? I got stuck right now... @BaronVT

Comment: The way you will construct your argument depends on which case you are considering; I have edited my answer to write out a proof for the first case.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I see... Thank you!! :-) @BaronVT

Answer (score 0):

Actually i would like to post a better answer (mpre intuitive) but anyway

Since the $\overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{b}, \overrightarrow{c}$ vectors are on the same plane (given) either they are all zero or all on same line (which lies of course on the plane) or two of them in same line and the other on the plane not on same line.

The last case assumes implicitly that any two points (on a plane) define a unique line

So if the three points are not all co-linear, either two of them (pick any two) define a unique line and are co-linear, and the remaining third is not

Comment: "Lie on the same line" in this context has an implicit "... through the origin" added to them. So while you're technically correct in your treatment of whether the points $a,b$ and $c$ are coplanar or not, your answer does not help toward the original goal of showing that there is a non-trivial linear combination of the vectors that add up $\vec0$.

Comment: @Arthur, yes correct, the proof then uses the fact that any co-linear points have a similar linear relation betwen them (which i assume from the phrasing of the question it is to be used)

Comment: @Arthur, please the downvote is wrong, the question asks why these three cases, the answer is about that, the question is not about the whole proof of this.

Comment: But you say "or two of them are on the same line and one is not". This is not true, since none of the three vectors $$(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,0)$$lie on the same line, yet they are coplanar, and there is a combination of them that give the zero vector.

Comment: @Arthur, you are wrong, any 2 points define a unique line, any two of your example can define a unique line and be co-linear

Comment: @Arthur, some people here on these sites think that downvoting will somehow magicaly **change the fact of the argument** and make it wrong. Really as long as peolle are willing to see the actual argument, i dont give a shit baby

Comment: But if we use your interpretation of coplanar, then $$(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$$lie on a plane, but there is no nontrivial linear combination that give the zero vector. You have to interpret "$\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ lie on the same plane" as "they lie on the same plane _containing the origin_", otherwise the problem makes no sense. And I'm not downvoting to make you wrong, I'm formfitting to show others that I think you've misunderstood something, and that IMO this answer is not to be trusted.

Comment: Nikos: Moderators are not arbiters of correctness. Flagging a comment asking for a ruling is futile. We only examine voting, if it is serial (and/or otherwise unrelated to mathematical content). I do want to make a comment that the formulation of the question is somewhat ambiguos in the sense that it is not clear what Mary Star means when she says *... are on the same plane*. You seem to have interpreted the meaning of that differently than Arthur. So noted. Move on.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, the comment is still wrong and not a matter of interpretation. The example vectors he gives in the comments for any two of them define a line and are co-linear. Apart from that the very first comment which is supoposed to "explain" the downvote has been addressed to the point. The rest is just an excuse. BTw i dont see offering same advice to the other side to ammend the downvote and move on (even out of mere tact and fair play). Double standards.

Comment: IMO the phrase "two vectors are collinear" is meaningless (or, broken English) unless it means that they are scalar multiples of each other. Vector $\neq$ its end point. At least according to some. Which is exactly the source of the different interpretations. And. Once more. Moderators are not here to police how people choose to vote. Someone (we don't know who it was) felt that your answer is not useful to the OP. Happens here frequently. Shrug. No double standard. To learn more search relevant stuff in [Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/). Many new users are frustrated by downvotes.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, well ok this could easily be rephrased (to mean the points in the comments), and indeed "point phraseology" and "vector phraseology" are indeed inter-changeable (in most mathematical contexts, anyway) still does not make it wrong, it is still a pretext or excuse. Based on good will these shades of meaning or phraseology (if i can use such word) are easily resolved to the benefit of all. As for the rest, sure i agree no need for policing anyone.Still i demand to be ammended, whether it is moderator's responsibility or not and in any case a position has been taken.